# Paypal Api Do not pass PAY-XXX or PAYID-XXX directly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

Everything in my system was in good condition, but since yesterday I get an error like this I could not understand why?

> Error: Do not pass PAY-XXX or PAYID-XXX directly into createOrder. Pass the EC-XXX token instead

This is my Smart Payment Button script

```html
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          color: 'black',
          shape: 'rect',
          label: 'paypal',
          tagline: false,
          size: 'responsive',
        },

        createOrder: function() {

          var SETEC_URL = '/api/create-payment';
          var checkBox = document.getElementById("ship_to_different");
          var note = $("#ordernote").val();
          if (checkBox.checked == true) {
            var body = $("#checkoutt, #data").serializeArray();
          } else {
            $('input[name=note]').val(note);
            var body = $("#data").serializeArray();

          }
          $("#wait").show();
          return fetch(SETEC_URL, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              body: body
            })

          }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
          }).then(function(data) {
            return data.id;
          });


        },
        commit: false,
        onApprove: function(data) {

          var EXECUTE_URL = '/api/execute-payment';
          return fetch(EXECUTE_URL, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              paymentID: data.paymentID,
              payerID: data.payerID,

            })
          }).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);

              if (response.statusText == 'OK') {
                var checkBox =
                  document.getElementById("ship_to_different");
                var note = $("#ordernote").val();
                if (checkBox.checked == true) {
                  var xdata = $("#checkoutt, #data").serialize();
                } else {
                  $('input[name=note]').val(note);
                  var xdata = $("#data").serialize();
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'check-data',
                    data: xdata,
                    success: function() {
                      $("#wait").hide();
                      $("#success").show();
                    },
                    error: function(request) {
                      json = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
                      $.each(json.errors, function(key, value) {
                          $('#error' + key).html('');
                          $('#error' + key).append('<p 
                            class = "erro" > '+value+' < /p>');
                          });
                      }
                    });
                }
              })
          }, onError: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

This is my backend Create-Payment function:

```
public function createorder(Request $request){

    $body = json_decode(json_encode($request['body']),true);

    foreach($body as $valpay){
        if($valpay['name'] == '_token'){
            unset($valpay);
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'title[]'){
            $titlepay[] = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'product_id[]'){
            $product_idpay[] = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'price[]'){
            $pricepay[] = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'quantity[]'){
            $quantitypay[] = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'ssh'){
            $shippingpay = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'total'){
            $totalpay = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'subtotal'){
            $subtotalpay = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'tax'){
            $taxpay = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'city'){
            $city = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'country'){
            $country = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'state'){
            $state = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'street'){
            $street = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'zip'){
            $zip = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'coupon'){
            $coupon = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'discount'){
            $discount = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'data'){
            $data = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'x1'){
            $gift = $valpay['value'];
        }elseif($valpay['name'] == 'cost'){
            $cost = $valpay['value'];
        }

    }


    $apiContext = new  ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            'clientid',
            'secret'
        ));
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");


    if(isset($gift)){
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName('Gift Coupon')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity('1')
            ->setPrice($cost);
        $items[] = $item;
        $subtotalpay = $cost;
        $totalpay = $cost;
    }else{
        foreach ($product_idpay as $key => $p_id){
            $item[$key] = new Item();
            $item[$key]->setName($titlepay[$key])
                ->setCurrency('USD')
                ->setQuantity($quantitypay[$key])
                ->setSku("123123") 
                ->setPrice($pricepay[$key]);
            $items[] = $item[$key];
        }
    }


    if(isset($coupon)){

        $subtotalpay = $coupon;
        $item[$key+1] = new Item();
        $item[$key+1]->setName('Coupon')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity("1")
            ->setSku("test") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice('-'.$discount);
        $items[] = $item[$key+1];
    }

    if($taxpay == '1'){
        $tax = round($subtotalpay * 8.625/100,2);

    }else{
        $tax = 0;
    }
    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems($items);


    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping($shippingpay)
        ->setTax($tax)
        ->setSubtotal($subtotalpay);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal($totalpay)
        ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("http://homee.test/checkout")
        ->setCancelUrl("http://homee.test/checkout");

    $inputFields = new InputFields();
    $inputFields->setNoShipping(1);

    $webProfile = new WebProfile();
    $webProfile->setName('test'. uniqid())->setInputFields($inputFields);
    $webProfileId = $webProfile->create($apiContext)->getId();
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setExperienceProfileId($webProfileId);
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $request = clone $payment;

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
        echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message
        die($ex);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex);
    }

    $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

    return $payment;
}
```

And this is Execute-Payment function

```
public function execute(Request $request){

    $apiContext = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            'clientid',
            'secret'
        ));


    $paymentId = $request->paymentID;
    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($request->payerID);

    try{
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
        $res = $result->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->id;
        $res2 = $result->transactions[0]->invoice_number;
        $res3 = $result->getId();

        Transactions::create([
            'ip' => \Request::ip(),
            'transaction_id' => $res,
            'invoice_id' => $res2,
            'payment_id' => $res3
        ]);
        Refunds::create([
            'ip' => \Request::ip(),
            'transaction_id' => $res,
            'invoice_id' => $res2,
            'payment_id' => $res3,
            'amount' => '0'
        ]);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }


}

public function validateorder(Request $request)
{
    if($request['status']) {
        $messages = array(
            'zip' => 'Post Code Field is Required.'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'street' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',


        ]);
    }elseif($request['guest']) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'street' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',


        ]);
    }elseif($request['x1']) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required'

        ]);
    }
        try
        {
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
        }

    }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If any one getting same problem like this i was able to find work around from this one now i have tried the solution with python but i think if any one can do the same thing from any other language

payPal sending us a array of link so what i am doing is getting the link from the list

```
    {
   "intent":"sale",
   "payer":{
      "payment_method":"paypal"
   },
   "redirect_urls":{
      "return_url":"http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
      "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/"
   },
   "transactions":[
      {
         "amount":{
            "total":"5.00",
            "currency":"USD"
         },
         "description":"This is the payment transaction description.",
         "item_list":{
            "items":[
               {
                  "name":"item",
                  "sku":"item",
                  "price":"5.00",
                  "currency":"USD",
                  "quantity":1
               }
            ]
         },
         "related_resources":[
            
         ]
      }
   ],
   "id":"PAYID-MG5D3JA33asdasdasdasdASDASD815R",
   "state":"created",
   "create_time":"2021-12-15T19:10:28Z",
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MG5SSDASDASDSADSAKD564815R",
         "rel":"self",
         "method":"GET"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5K121231232094281T",
         "rel":"approval_url",
         "method":"REDIRECT"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MG5ADSADASDASDSA4564815R/execute",
         "rel":"execute",
         "method":"POST"
      }
   ]
}
```

then i am getting the array of links and search for

> approval_url
> Then do small regex/search and get the code

```
token = ''

links = payment.links
for i in links:
    if(i.rel=="approval_url"):
        token = i.href.split("EC-",1)[1]
return token
```

and if you pass this one it will work.
i don't know why PayPal send this inside a URL this makes it extra work to retrieve but it's work. hope this one helps any one since we can't find this in documentation in PayPal

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Thalinda Bandara for his answer. if anyone looking for js code here is:

Javascript:

```
var token = '';
var links = payment.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].rel === 'approval_url') {
        token = links[i].href.split('EC-', 2)[1];
    }
}
return token;
```